# Second minimum value for every customer

Tags: sql, date, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL database. So, there are two columns I am working on, CustomerId, and OrderDate. I want to find a second-order date (2nd minimum order date) for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` can be used here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY OrderDate) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT CustomerId, OrderDate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding, The thing is that window functions don't work in the MySQL version that I am using. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you have duplicate dates per customer?

Comment: Yes, there can be.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `dense_rank` as it can give you correct result even if there is duplicate `order_date` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY OrderDate) dr
    FROM yourTable t
) t where dr = 2;
```

You can use corelated sub-query as follows if your MySQL version do not support analytical functions as follows:

```
SELECT T.*
  FROM YOURTABLE T
 WHERE 1 = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_DATE)
      FROM YOURTABLE TT
     WHERE TT.ORDER_DATE > T.ORDER_DATE
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. Is there any way to do this without using window functions? I am using MySQL 5.7 which doesn't support window functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery like this:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.order_date = (select o2.order_date
                      from orders o2
                      where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id
                      order by o2.order_date
                      limit 1 offset 1
                     );
```

The subquery is a *correlated subquery* that returns the second date.  If you want the second date with other columns, it can be moved to the `select`.

With an index on `(customer_id, order_date)`, this is likely to be the fastest solution.

This assumes that there is one row per date (or that if there are multiple rows, "second" can be the earliest date).  If you want the second distinct date then use `select distinct` int he subquery -- however `select distinct` and `group by` would incur additional overhead.